Is the DC password policy affecting user account made in a block exception OU
I am setting up user accounts for MAB (Mac Authentication Bypass) devices on my network. In GPO I have made an OU for the device accounts to be created with block inheritance so that the password policy is not applied to the device accounts. The password policy does apply to the Domain Controller. When I go to make the account for the device the username/password must be the mac address of the device. Problem is even with the block inheritance set on the OU when I got to make the user account in that OU it still enforces the password policy. Without turning the policy with the password policy off, is there a way to make the user account for the MAB deivce?

To whoever voted to close this question: I'm NOT VTC it.; there are plausible reasons to want exceptions to the global domain password policy, and there is a supported way to do that. The OP doesn't seem to know how to achieve this, and I'm trying to explain it. But this is not an "unreasonable IT management practice".

The password policy which is applied to Domain Controllers affects all users in the domain, regardless of where you place them in the Active Directory tree. OU inheritance is completely unrelated.
You can use fine grained password policies to apply different password policies to specific users (or group of users).

I have made one for users in that group and OU but when making the account in A/D it still says it doesn't meet the password policy. When making FGPP do I have to remove the password policy settings on the GPOs?

A FGPP is applied to accounts or groups, not to OUs. OUs are completely unrelated. A FGPP is used to create a specific exception from the global domain password policy, which is defined in the GPO applied to Domain Controllers.

I got it figured out. Thanks for your help!
